# Evaluate if two doubles are equal based on a given precision, not within a certain fixed tolerance

Tags: c#, nunit, floating-point

I'm running NUnit tests to evaluate some known test data and calculated results.  The numbers are floating point doubles so I don't expect them to be exactly equal, but I'm not sure how to treat them as equal for a given precision.

In NUnit we can compare with a fixed tolerance:

```
double expected = 0.389842845321551d;
double actual   = 0.38984284532155145d; // really comes from a data import
Expect(actual, EqualTo(expected).Within(0.000000000000001));
```

and that works fine for numbers below zero, but as the numbers grow the tolerance really needs to be changed so we always care about the same number of digits of precision.

Specifically, this test fails:

```
double expected = 1.95346834136148d;
double actual   = 1.9534683413614817d; // really comes from a data import
Expect(actual, EqualTo(expected).Within(0.000000000000001));
```

and of course larger numbers fail with tolerance..

```
double expected = 1632.4587642911599d;
double actual   = 1632.4587642911633d; // really comes from a data import
Expect(actual, EqualTo(expected).Within(0.000000000000001));
```

What's the correct way to evaluate two floating point numbers are equal with a given precision? Is there a built-in way to do this in NUnit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From msdn:

> By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

Let's assume 15, then.

So, we could say that we want the tolerance to be to the same degree.

How many precise figures do we have after the decimal point?  We need to know the distance of the most significant digit from the decimal point, right?  The magnitude.  We can get this with a Log10.

Then we need to divide 1 by 10 ^ precision to get a value around the precision we want.

Now, you'll need to do more test cases than I have, but this seems to work:

```
  double expected = 1632.4587642911599d;
  double actual = 1632.4587642911633d; // really comes from a data import

  // Log10(100) = 2, so to get the manitude we add 1.
  int magnitude = 1 + (expected == 0.0 ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(expected))));
  int precision = 15 - magnitude ;

  double tolerance = 1.0 / Math.Pow(10, precision);

  Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected).Within(tolerance));
```

It's late - there could be a gotcha in here.  I tested it against your three sets of test data and each passed.  Changing `pricision` to be `16 - magnitude` caused the test to fail.  Setting it to `14 - magnitude` obviously caused it to pass as the tolerance was greater.

Comment: This is a very good solution, but generates an exception when comparing `0.0` to `0.0`.  A simple `if` condition around `expected` would take care of that though.

Comment: Ah yes.  I thought there would be something. :)  I have updated my answer to take account of this.

Comment: this worked really well.  I ran 105 unit tests, about half positive and half negative, and all but 8 passed.  Michael Borgwardt's answer passed and failed the exact same tests.

Comment: @Samuel Neff, what were the failed test cases?

Comment: `int magnitude = 1 + (Math.Abs(expected) < 1E-15 ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(expected)))));` — this will fix case with negative expected value and comparison to zero. Did any one use this code with negative values before?

Answer (score 10):

This is what I came up with for [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) (Java code, but should translate easily, and comes with a test suite, which you really really need):

```
public static boolean nearlyEqual(float a, float b, float epsilon)
{
    final float absA = Math.abs(a);
    final float absB = Math.abs(b);
    final float diff = Math.abs(a - b);

    if (a * b == 0) { // a or b or both are zero
        // relative error is not meaningful here
        return diff < (epsilon * epsilon);
    } else { // use relative error
        return diff / (absA + absB) < epsilon;
    }
}
```

The really tricky question is what to do when one of the numbers to compare is zero. The best answer may be that such a comparison should always consider the domain meaning of the numbers being compared rather than trying to be universal.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt, what exactly is epsilon? what does a value of 0.0001 actually man in comparisons? Through testing I can find appropriate values for epsilon that work for my test data (both true when expected and false when expected), but I'm not 100% clear on this parameter.

Comment: @Samuel: epsilon is a relative error margin, i.e. epsilon of 0.01 means the difference between the 2 values must be less than about 1%. But if one value is 0, this becomes meaningless, so in that case I require the other value to be smaller than epsilon squared. That's pretty arbitrary; thus the conclusion that a universally useful comparison function may not exists.

Comment: @Michael Bordwardt, thanks, that's a good explanation.  I understand and agree with your statement about a universally useful comparison function, but unfortunately this is for a library, not a specific enterprise app, so I'm looking for something that is as universal as possible.  I'm still doing some more testing, both your solution and Bretts (simpler, less neat) solution seem to work in the same cases and fail in the same cases.

Comment: @Michael Bordwardt, this formula worked really well.  I came up with 105 unit tests (about half positive and half negative).  only 8 of the tests failed.  Interestingly, Brett's response is a very different formula and failed on the exact same tests and passed the exact same tests.  I changed those 8 tests to make the numbers very slightly different and so they passed as well.

Comment: @Samuel: cenceptually, the two methods test more or less the same thing, though I wouldn't have expected them to behave the same to *that* degree. Just to make sure, and something I noticed is missing in my test suite: Do you have test cases comparing positive and negative zeroes, infinites and NaNs?

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt, thanks for the suggestions.  I was primarily just testing with variations of the actual data from the test data I was using for the data import tool where this will be used.  I added another 29 tests, added some special cases for those you mentioned, and in 7 tests Brett's solution passed whereas your formula failed.  These are the first tests where I found a difference.  If you'd like I'll be happy to e-mail you the complete test data.

Comment: @Samuel: thanks, my address is brazzy@gmail.com - most likely those cases can be fixed by adding an additional `if(a==b) return true` branch.

Answer (score 8):

```
Assert.That(x, Is.EqualTo(y).Within(10).Percent);
```

is a decent option (changes it to a relative comparison, where x is required to be within 10% of y).  You may want to add extra handling for 0, as otherwise you'll get an exact comparison in that case.

Update:
Another good option is

```
Assert.That(x, Is.EqualTo(y).Within(1).Ulps);
```

where `Ulps` means `units in the last place`.  See https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/EqualConstraint.html#comparing-floating-point-values.

Answer (score 6):

How about converting the items each to string and comparing the strings?

```
string test1 = String.Format("{0:0.0##}", expected);
string test2 = String.Format("{0:0.0##}", actual);
Assert.AreEqual(test1, test2);
```

Comment: I've thought of this and agree it would work to convert to strings.  Not like you said exactly though, you'd want to convert to strings using the full precision available for each value and then truncate them at the same length.  However, I'm hoping for a mathematically appropriate result, something a little less hacky.

Comment: This solution would mean `0.99999999999999999999` would be unequal `1.00000000000000000000` - but that's not intended, is it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there's a built-in way to do it with nunit, but I would suggest multiplying each float by the 10x the precision you're seeking, storing the results as longs, and comparing the two longs to each other.
For example:

```
double expected = 1632.4587642911599d;
double actual   = 1632.4587642911633d;
//for a precision of 4
long lActual = (long) 10000 * actual;
long lExpected = (long) 10000 * expected;

if(lActual == lExpected) {  // Do comparison
   // Perform desired actions
}
```

Comment: This is mathematically identical to using a tolerance, it's just being applied in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick idea, but how about shifting them down till they are below zero? Should be something like `num/(10^ceil(log10(num)))` . . . not to sure about how well it would work, but its an idea.

```
1632.4587642911599 / (10^ceil(log10(1632.4587642911599))) = 0.16324587642911599
```

Comment: This does look like a good start at least.  What effect does this calculation have on precision? is there a loss of precision? Obviously I don't care about full precision of both comparable values, but if we lose precision in both then the comparison may yield some false positives.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
const double significantFigures = 10;
Assert.AreEqual(Actual / Expected, 1.0, 1.0 / Math.Pow(10, significantFigures));
```

Comment: Of course if expected value is zero or close to it, you'll have to code a special case. How many significant digits does zero have? Zero or infinite?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two values should be less than either value divided by the precision.

```
Assert.Less(Math.Abs(firstValue - secondValue), firstValue / Math.Pow(10, precision));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NUnit, the [`[DefaultFloatingPointTolerance]`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/defaultfloatingpointtolerance.html) attribute can be used on a class, method, or assembly to control the tolerance when comparing between `float` and `double` values.

```cs
[TestFixture]
[DefaultFloatingPointTolerance(1)]
public class ToleranceTest
{
    [Test]
    public void ComparisonUsingDefaultFloatingPointToleranceFromFixture()
    {
        // Passes due to the DefaultFloatingPointToleranceAttribute from the fixture.
        Assert.That(1f, Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void ComparisonOfIntegersDoNotUseTolerance()
    {
        // Fails as DefaultFloatingPointTolerance only effects comparisons
        // of floats and doubles.
        Assert.That(1, Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void ComparisonUsingSpecificTolerance()
    {
        // Fails as 1 is not equal to 2 using the specified tolerance 0.
        Assert.That(1f, Is.EqualTo(2).Within(0));
    }

    [Test]
    [DefaultFloatingPointTolerance(2)]
    public void ComparisonUsingDefaultFloatingPointToleranceFromTest()
    {
        // Passes due to the  DefaultFloatingPointTolerance from the test.
        Assert.That(2f, Is.EqualTo(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional option and information, useful but not for this question. Isn't it exactly what the question says does not fit the use case? The title says "**not within a certain fixed tolerance**." It was years ago, but the accepted answer is what I used and it worked very well.

Answer (score -1):

open FsUnit

actual |> should (equalWithin errorMargin) expected